# Which is faster for commuting, kick scooter or skateboard?

Tags: scooters

Before spending money on buying a kick scooter, I want to ask around on which is faster.

I searched on some forums but the answers may be biased (skaters). I have been using a cruiser board for some time.

The road to commute may have up and down hills and some obstacles and speed ramps, can a kick scooter go faster and require less energy?